# how to fix docker crashing when adding insecure registry so I can run openshift

Tags: macos, docker, openshift

Docker Engine (on mac) crashes when adding the insecure registry and pressing Apply and Restart

I am adding the insecure registry setting that the terminal suggests when I run the oc cluster up command to start my openshift portal.

```
openshift/openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.9.0-alpha.3-78ddc10-mac
$ oc cluster up
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.9.0-alpha.3 ...
Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.9.0-alpha.3
Pulled 1/4 layers, 26% complete
<snip>
Pulled 3/4 layers, 99% complete
Pulled 4/4 layers, 100% complete
Extracting
Image pull complete
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... OK
-- Checking Docker version ... OK
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v3.9.0-alpha.3 image ...
   Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.9.0-alpha.3
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 26% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 34% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 45% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 48% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 53% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 57% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 61% complete
   Pulled 1/4 layers, 66% complete
   Pulled 2/4 layers, 72% complete
   Pulled 2/4 layers, 76% complete
   Pulled 2/4 layers, 80% complete
   Pulled 2/4 layers, 81% complete
   Pulled 2/4 layers, 88% complete
   Pulled 3/4 layers, 93% complete
   Pulled 3/4 layers, 99% complete
   Pulled 4/4 layers, 100% complete
   Extracting
   Image pull complete
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... FAIL
   Error: did not detect an --insecure-registry argument on the Docker daemon
   Solution:

{
     Ensure that the Docker daemon is running with the following argument:
        --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16
{

     You can run this command with --create-machine to create a machine with the
     right argument.
```

It is a vanilla install of docker for mac, no customisations.

expected outcome: docker restarts and I can rerun my command

actual outcome: docker encounters an error and suggests three choices: revert to factory settings, diagnose or exit.

Comment: Also confirm what version of Docker for Mac are you using? Last version I know works is ``Version 17.09.0-ce-mac35 (19611) Channel: stable a98b7c1b7c``. They broke newer versions of Docker in a way which causes ``oc cluster up`` to not work for other reasons beyond the insecure registry setup, and waiting for Docker for Mac to be fixed.

Comment: Version 17.12.0-ce-mac47 (21805)  Channel: stable  b13a2e427c

Comment: Also should add that I have had no success getting oc 3.9.0-alpha.3 for ``oc cluster up`` to work as yet. Better to stick with 3.7.1.

Comment: It worked :) 
    Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.9.0-alpha.3 ...
    OpenShift server started.

    The server is accessible via web console at:
    https://127.0.0.1:8443

Comment: Lucky for you. I get errors about certificates being out of date when it starts up and health checks failing. For me it could be a timing issue due to the slow internet I have and need to pull down large images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue the other day actually!

After updating the insecure registry setting using the GUI on the Mac OSX client, Docker wouldn’t start up. Make sure you press exit - don’t press revert to factory settings, otherwise you will lose all your images & containers…

I went here:

~/.docker/daemon.cfg

Disabled experimental features, which had sporadically enabled itself.

I then added the insecure registry manually, and restarted Docker.

~/.docker/daemon.cfg should look something like like this:

```
$ cat ~/.docker/daemon.json
{
  "debug" : true,
  "insecure-registries" : [
    “172.30.0.0/16”
  ],
  "experimental" : false
}
```

Hey presto, it worked! :)

HTH!

Comment: Ah, I wish I'd known that... I pressed revert first as I'm sure most people would try in the first instance, and then it failed to restart properly. must be a bug.

Comment: Just for completeness, here's the documentation https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md